Trying to detach disks from a VM using Golang API in Azure
I am trying to detach a list of currently attached disks using golang api, however the code does not seem to be detaching anything, I get no errors, however, the resource group is showing the disks as attached
func DetachDisks(azureEnvInfo AzureEnvInfo, cred *azidentity.DefaultAzureCredential) (err error) {

    ctx := context.Background()
    vmClient, err := armcompute.NewVirtualMachinesClient(azureEnvInfo.SubscriptionID, cred, nil)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to create vm client: %v", err)

        return err
    }

    // Get the VM instance
    vm, err := vmClient.Get(ctx, azureEnvInfo.ResourceGrpName, azureEnvInfo.VaultName, nil)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to get VM: %w", err)
        fmt.Print(err)
        return err
    }

    var keepDisks []*armcompute.DataDisk
    

    // Update the VM with the list of disks (excluding the ones you wish to detach)
    vm.Properties.StorageProfile.DataDisks = keepDisks
    vm.Properties.StorageProfile.OSDisk.DeleteOption = to.Ptr(armcompute.DiskDeleteOptionTypesDetach)
    // set the OS disk to nil to detach it
    vm.Properties.StorageProfile.OSDisk = nil

    vmProperties := armcompute.VirtualMachineUpdate{
        Properties: vm.Properties,
    }

    // Update the VM
    poller, err := vmClient.BeginUpdate(context.Background(), azureEnvInfo.ResourceGrpName, azureEnvInfo.VaultName, vmProperties, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to begin VM update: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    _, err = poller.PollUntilDone(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to update VM: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Data Disks detached successfully.")
    return nil
}

Expected to see the disks with a detached status in the resource manager view in azure.

Please edit to provide a [mcve]. right now you provided a lot of code but nothing else (no sample input, no expected behavior vs actual behavior...)


Trying to detach disks from a VM using Golang API in Azure

Here is the updated Golang code to detach all disk's in VM.
compile process
    mkdir myproject
    cd myproject
    go mod init myproject
    go run vm.go


Note: Make sure to install all required modules before executing the code

go get github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/compute/armcompute
go get github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity

I have 2 data disks attached to my VM

package main
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/compute/armcompute"
)

type AzureEnvInfo struct {
    SubscriptionID  string
    ResourceGrpName string
    VMName          string
}
func DetachAllDataDisks(azureEnvInfo AzureEnvInfo, cred *azidentity.DefaultAzureCredential) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    vmClient, err := armcompute.NewVirtualMachinesClient(azureEnvInfo.SubscriptionID, cred, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to create VM client: %v", err)
    }
    vm, err := vmClient.Get(ctx, azureEnvInfo.ResourceGrpName, azureEnvInfo.VMName, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to get VM: %w", err)
    }
    for _, disk := range vm.Properties.StorageProfile.DataDisks {
        if disk.Name != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Detaching Disk: %s from VM: %s\n", *disk.Name, azureEnvInfo.VMName)
        }
    }
    vm.Properties.StorageProfile.DataDisks = []*armcompute.DataDisk{}

    DataDisks
    vmUpdate := armcompute.VirtualMachineUpdate{
        Properties: &armcompute.VirtualMachineProperties{
            StorageProfile: &armcompute.StorageProfile{
                DataDisks: vm.Properties.StorageProfile.DataDisks,
            },
        },
    }
    poller, err := vmClient.BeginUpdate(ctx, azureEnvInfo.ResourceGrpName, azureEnvInfo.VMName, vmUpdate, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to begin VM update: %v", err)
    }
    _, err = poller.PollUntilDone(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to update VM: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("All data disks detached successfully.")
    return nil
}

func main() {

    azureEnvInfo := AzureEnvInfo{
        SubscriptionID:  "158xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-4d98-95c5-f21815dd048f",
        ResourceGrpName: "Venkat",
        VMName:          "VenkatVM",
    }

    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to obtain a credential: %v", err)
    }

    err = DetachAllDataDisks(azureEnvInfo, cred)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to detach all data disks: %v", err)
    }
}

go run vm.go output
After executing the code, the disks are detached successfully from VM.

Portal view


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Aside from that: the OP provided a lot of code but no details (no debugging info, no input... nothing). And what you provided is also a large block of "updated" code, but without doing a diff, it's not clear what's different. In the case of this question, it's much better to comment under the question to get clarification, and not attempt to rewrite some code, when the OP hasn't given any specifics other than "it doesn't work"
